# MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() reflection line explanation

Tags: c#, reflection, syntax, .net-3.5

I'm transitioning from C++ to C# and I have a method call that's confusing me.  I think I might be able to guess what it does, but I'd appreciate an expert just telling me straight:

```
WDResult returnValue = (WDResult)Invoke(
    (MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(),
    new object[] { request, loadType });
```

It looks to me like it's using reflection to infoke the method that's already being invoked.  I can't understand why one would do that if that is the case though.  Also, why would you do it with reflection instead of just a recursion call?  Note that in the code, a different overload is not being used in the call.  The parameters request and loadType are pretty much passed straight into this code in the first line of the function it appears in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's calling a custom `Invoke()` method, which takes a `MethodInfo`.
It isn't standard reflection.

Look in the `Invoke()` method to see why they're doing that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was it?

Comment: Its called in many places.  It takes whatever command was going on in the calling function and handles it in a generic way to zip arguments (they're large), provide encryption, and dispatch to a rpc api.  I'm not quite sure what it was intended for in the original design though - it looks more like a cover-all patch - all functions were forwarded to this one, and the parameters let this one deal with the original request dynamically while providing the compression/encryption/dispatching.  My guess is the RPC api didn't used to be used and it was previously local calls.

Comment: Unfortunately my "Go To Definition" wasn't working for some reason until I reopened visual studio, so I thought it was something more complex :(

Answer (score 1):

> Also, why would you do it with reflection instead of just a recursion call?

You can copy paste that line into other methods and it will still work, provided they take the same arguments.